# POST request received but never return with payload on Tomcat behind Nginx

Tags: tomcat, nginx, jax-rs, httpresponse, jersey-2.0

**Server setup and libraries**

I am writing a Java web application with Jersey 2.26 (for RESTFul API development). I have my Tomcat server running on port 8080 running behind NGINX (as a reverse proxy on port 80) and all works well except following scenario.

**Problem:**

POST methods return a 404 error when tomcat responds with a payload. I think the error is from NGINX since the 404 error page doesn't look like the usual 404 message from Tomcat server(one with greyish blue colour and white). I added my NGIN config to bottom of the page. It looks to me the connection between NGINX and Tomcat is lost/disconnected when there is payload on the response.

Following 3 code snippet captures 3 ways I tried to isolate the problem. I have other application running on same server configuration that use Servlets instead of Jersey JEE stuff and they all work fine. Only the application that use JAX-RS api having the problem. Each sinippet contains a description of result of making a POST request to port 80 (NGINX) and 8080 (Tomcat).

**Snippet 1:**

1. Can access through NGINX and returns 200 Response i.e http://domain/upload
2. Can access through Tomcat and returns 200 Response i.e http://domain:8080/upload
3. Notice there is no payload

```java
@POST
@Path("/upload")
public Response upload(@Context HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

**Snippet 2:**  Wants to get this working since its the proper way to code

1. Post request through NGINX reaches server and print "Request reached server" message to console but displays a 404 page. Seems like it is from NGINX rather than Tomcat i.e see the error message below
2. Can access through TOMCA print "Request reached server" message to console and returns 200 Response with "HELLO" i.e http://domain:8080/upload
3. Notice this has a payload

```java
@POST
@Path("/upload")
public Response upload(@Context HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    String output = "HELLO";
    System.out.println("Request reached server");
    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
}
```

**Snippet 3:**

1. Works on both NGINX and Tomcat

```java
@POST
@Path("/upload")
public void upload(@Context HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    response.getWriter().write("HELLO\n");
    response.getWriter().flush();
    response.getWriter().close();
}
```

404 Error reply:

```xml
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

NGINX config

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  domainname;
    client_max_body_size 2000m;

    gzip on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types    text/plain application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text/xml text/css;
    expires max;
    root /usr/local/nginx/html;


    #Static files
    location ~ \.(js|css|jpeg|jpg|png|scss|ttf|woff|woff2) { 
        root   /home/user/domainname;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;

        proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/tomcat/;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 1024m;
    }


    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/local/nginx/html;
    }

}
```

Appreciate any effort to solve this problem...

Comment: Have you tried adding `@Produces` to the method? Like `@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)`